# How to select value in dropdown menu in ruby watir without knowing the value?

Tags: ruby, testing, select, watir, dropdown

I'm trying to select something from a dropdown menu, without knowing what are the options. The code needs to work for many users and everyone has different values.

```
<select name="aspx_accountinformation_accountstatementsearch_ascxTRANSACTION_HISTORY1dfe5e76-b83a-4957-84c3-16e8ae795e9c$ddlAccount" id="aspx_accountinformation_accountstatementsearch_ascxTRANSACTION_HISTORY1dfe5e76-b83a-4957-84c3-16e8ae795e9c_ddlAccount" class="selectM">
                        <option value="Selectare">Selectare</option>
                        <option value="226523531-Card">226523531-232-MDL</option>

                    </select>
```

For now I was only found how to do it knowing the options, like this:

```
browser.option(:text,'226523531-232-MDL').click
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure whether I understood your question correctly,

If you want to select the first option all the time, then

```
locator='aspx_accountinformation_accountstatementsearch_ascxTRANSACTION_HISTORY1dfe5e76-b83a-4957-84c3-16e8ae795e9c$ddlAccount'

b.select_list(name: locator).options.first.select
```

If you want to select some random option, then

```
b.select_list(name: locator).options.to_a.sample.select
```

Comment: I want to select one of the options every time and I want to be able to specify if its the first or 2nd, 3rd etc. I tried your code but I get an error
`C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/watir-6.10.3/lib/watir/elements/element.rb:664:in `rescue in element_call': element located, but timed out after 30 seconds, waiting for #<Watir::Select: located: false; {:name=>"aspx_accountinformation_accountstatementsearch_ascxTRANSACTION_HISTORY1dfe5e76-b83a-4957-84c3-16e8ae795e9c$ddlAccount", :tag_name=>"select"}> to be present; Maybe look in an iframe? (Watir::Exception::UnknownObjectException)
`

Comment: @Alexandru Pereira 
Then try using `b.select_list().Options[1].select ` and second option use [2]

Comment: I changed it a little to this `browser.select_list().option[1].select` but get the error C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/watir-6.10.3/lib/watir/elements/element.rb:688:in `method_missing': undefined method `[]' for #<Watir::Option:0x0000000005db9b10> (NoMethodError)

Comment: You need to use the plural form "optionS": `browser.select_list().options[1].select`

Comment: Read my comment I have written `options` not `option`.

Comment: @Rajagopalan I was responding to @AlexandruMereuta who wrote `option`. But in your comment the capital "O" does not work.

Comment: @pjd yes it doesn't , I was actually indicating the syntax to him, yeah you are right I must have taken care of that.